# UK visit visa after Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, schengen-visas

Me and my husband (non eu) are planning a trip to Germany and then UK to visit my family. We will be in Germany for 3 months and then go to the UK. Does anyone know if it is possible to forward date a UK visit visa or is it only valid from the date that its issued?

As we have to apply for UK visa before we go to Germany the 6 months will expire before we had originally planned to leave the UK.

Answer (score 2):

They will forward-date a UK visa **up to three months** from the application date if you advise them of this in the application.

> Where an applicant may not intend or be able to travel to the UK
>   immediately following their application they can apply for a visa at
>   any time before the date of travel to the UK, however, we can only
>   defer the start date of the visa up to a maximum 3 months from the
>   date of application.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entry-clearance-vignettes-ecb09/ecb09-entry-clearance-vignettes-types-safeguarding-and-validity

Based upon what you wrote, you can also apply in Germany nearer to the time of your planned visit.  It is not necessary to get it before leaving your home country.

> You can make applications for a visit visa or EEA family permit in any
>   visa application centre, British diplomatic mission or consular post
>   overseas where entry clearance applications are accepted.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy